# Is it possible to reduce the number of assignment operations in array exchange?

Tags: java, arrays, oop, coding-style

This method has a very simple behavior, as you can see. However, I was wondering if there's a way to simplify this code even further, since it's only doing assignment operations in order to exchange values from the array.

```
private Board exch(Board a, int i, int j) { // exchange two elements in the array
    int temp = a.board[i];
    a.board[j] = a.board[i];
    a.board[i] = temp;
    return a;
}
```

Comment: Not to my knowledge. Also, you have an error in your logic.

Comment: Where's the error? Sorry, I don't see it.

Comment: Keeping the other lines as-is, should be `int temp = a.board[j]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Algorithmically there is no better way, but if you are just trying to save lines of coding you can always do this:

```
​import java.util.Collections

//define your array

Collections.swap(arr, i, j);
```

after this arr will have the values swapped

Answer (score 1):

In this particular case that you are using ints, there is a way to do this without using a temp variable, by using math expressions, but I wouldn't recommend it just because it makes the code less readable.

```java
private Board exch(Board a, int i, int j) {
    a.board[i] = a.board[i] + a.board[j];
    a.board[j] = a.board[i] - a.board[j];
    a.board[i] = a.board[i] - a.board[j];
    return a;
}
```

Anyway, doing swaps the way you did is pretty common, so I am not sure why are you expecting to simplify even further